# Blackmailing from Germany

Tags: criminal-law, internet, privacy, germany, blackmail

I don’t know from where I should start but I am from Arabic Sudan and my Ex BF who lives in Germany is blackmailing me with private photos and videos he threat that he with post all over and send it to my family and friends.. he used a fake accounts ,many of them

I tried to use  Internetwach I understand no thing because no English in that site
I am completely lost I don’t know from where I should start or what to do
Please any help

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Internetwache Polizei Berlin](https://www.internetwache-polizei-berlin.de/) and klick on the (small) Flag below the Logo on the right side. That will give You access to an English version.

Please be aware that some offenses, especially those touching personal matters like Yours, require that additional to complaining to police (a "Strafanzeige") via Internet You'll need to sign a paper stating that You specifically want this complaint to be prosecuted (a "Strafantrag"). That paper needs to be mailed via traditional Post to the police.
Provide as many details as possible in the complaint. If You have more information afterwards, You can use the "Aktenzeichen" (file number) as reference in further correspondence.

The territorial jurisdiction of the Polizei Berlin is only in the federal state of Berlin, but they will forward Your complaint to the appropiate police authority. Given that the Internet awareness of the German police is still relatively low, You should not expect a fast response.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

From [this very good article](https://www.focus.de/finanzen/experten/bgh-hat-entschieden-strafbar-dann-kann-ich-von-meinem-ex-partner-das-loeschen-von-nacktfotos-verlangen_id_5169885.html) a Google translation which describes the according German law which your ex-boyfriend violates:

> In most cases, however, corresponding photos are taken with the consent of the person depicted or even made by the person himself and then sent or handed over. In these cases, §§ 33, 22 KunstUrhG protect against unauthorized distribution of these images.

> In these cases, however, it does not matter whether the photos are intimate or not. The dissemination of portraits of other people without their consent is generally prohibited by § 22 KunstUrhG. Failure to comply may result in imprisonment of up to one year or a fine in accordance with Section 33 of the KunstUrhG.

Here the link to the law [§§ 33, 22 KunstUrhG](https://dejure.org/gesetze/KunstUrhG/22.html) and [here](https://dejure.org/gesetze/KunstUrhG/33.html) what happens if you violate this law. Both links are in German but I assume your ex-boyfriend understands German? (you can do a Google-translation as well).

Probably your ex-boyfriend is not aware of this. Since you know his name and you can probably contact him, let him know that he violates this German law and that you are going to inform the police immediately if a picture of you pops up anywhere. If this is clearly communicated by you, it might solve your problem before pics are sent around.

Depending on the content of the pictures and your age, your ex-boyfriend might also violate the German "youth pornography law", see [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jugendpornografie) and do a Google translation in case you don't speak German.